# XML Annotation to add namespace prefix for each element to generate the wsdl

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

i'm generating a wsdl based on classes with the project jax-ws-commons.

Then, i'm importing that wsdl into my project and creating a service with the same plugin, but requests have not the namespace and prefix for each element, so i'm having requests like:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v="http://v1.ws.service">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <method>
            <session>
                <id>?</id>
            </session>
        </method>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

But i need something like:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v="http://v1.ws.service">
        <x:Header/>
        <x:Body>
            <v:method>
                <v:session>
                    <v:id>?</v:id>
                </v:session>
            </v:method>
        </x:Body>
    </x:Envelope>
```

When i imported the generated wsdl to soapui, requests are created fine, but when the requests is done with my project it isnt.

Any idea?

Comment: Both requests look similar.

Comment: Sorry now is fixed